# Does EBean (4.5.x) support mapping Java 8's time types such as OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, playframework, java-8, ebean

There is a [closed ticket](https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/178) suggesting that Ebean 4.4.1 and onwards supports Java 8's time classes, such as OffsetDateTime. However, I can't find any Ebean documentation showing the use these classes.

For a class such as `AppUser` shown below, is it fully supported to use OffsetDateTime instead of `java.sql.Timestamp`?

```
@Entity
public class AppUser extends Model {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private OffsetDateTime lastSeen;

    // Constructor, getters and setters
}
```

Comment: " is it fully supported to use OffsetDateTime instead of java.sql.Timestamp? " - yes it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no docs for these new types, but the code is pretty simple and straightforward:

https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/blob/master/src/main/java/com/avaje/ebeaninternal/server/type/ScalarTypeOffsetDateTime.java

As you can see at the code, `OffsetDateTime` is mapped to a `java.sql.Timestamp`. Here is a (likely) complete table of how Ebean maps `java.time` types to `java.sql.Types`:

```
| Java 8 java.time.*               | java.sql.Types |
|:---------------------------------|:---------------|
| DayOfWeek                        | INTEGER        |
| Duration                         | BIGINT         |
| Duration (with nanos precision)  | DECIMAL        |
| Instant                          | TIMESTAMP      |
| LocalDate                        | DATE           |
| LocalDateTime                    | TIMESTAMP      |
| LocalTime                        | TIME           |
| LocalTime (with nanos precision) | BIGINT         |
| Month                            | INTEGER        |
| MonthDay                         | DATE           |
| OffsetDateTime                   | TIMESTAMP      |
| OffsetTime                       | VARCHAR        |
| Year                             | INTEGER        |
| YearMonth                        | DATE           |
| ZoneId                           | VARCHAR        |
| ZoneOffset                       | VARCHAR        |
| ZonedDateTime                    | TIMESTAMP      |
```